# Ember.js & Play! framework authentication best practices

Tags: angularjs, authentication, ember.js, playframework-2.0

I'm using Ember client app completelly separate from Play! server. The Ember-CLI is used to build the client. The question is what libs to use (client and server sides) to authenticate Ember client on Play! server?

**update:**
What I need is token based authentication. There are [perfect series](http://www.embercasts.com/episodes/client-side-authentication-part-1) of screencasts about Ember client-side authentication. Also I fount [play2-auth](https://github.com/t2v/play2-auth) library for server side authentication and authorization. But I can't figure out how to setup it.

I think it's not a big problem to interpolate the solution from AngularJS-example if exists. So ng-funs are welcome!

Help please!

Answer (score 0):

One of the approaches is to use token based authentication. The comparison with cookies authentication can be found [here](https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/).

There is [JWT-authenticator](https://github.com/jpadilla/ember-cli-simple-auth-token) for [ember-simple-auth](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth) library for the client side.

On the other hand for the server side - [silhouette-rest-seed](https://github.com/merle-/silhouette-rest-seed). It's a good example of JWT-authentication implementation.

The only things needed to integrate the stuff are

- Name of the token header
- Credentials field names